# Passing parameters in BIP reports

Tags: oracle, crm, obiee, siebel, bi-publisher

I need to pass parameters to BIP report, I am using Siebel and reports are generated by the data from IO mapping (not sql query)

If I need to filter out some data should I manipulate it in siebel or should I just pass the parameters to BIP who should do the data manipulation based on the parameters passed to the report.

I can do any of them but would like to know what’s the standard Approach to pass parameters specially when reports are IO based?

Answer (score 0):

When BIP reports are triggered from Siebel, that data is NOT sent out. Instead, only the search specification and parameters are sent out, including the template name. BIP then invokes a second webservice with the searchspec which returns the data in XML for BIP processing.

If you plan to use parameters to filter, they have to be used in the template, which will work on a larger XML.

So, purely performance wise, it is better to filter the XML via the IO. This will result in a smaller XML coming back, and faster processing.

The parameters can be used to pass static text information on the [report](https://www.siebelhub.com/main/2012/04/siebel-bi-publisher-reports-parameter-enhancements.html).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You, this is very informative. However can you plz share a sample request that BIP uses to send search specification to Siebel ?